# Delete Old Items from Product List Using LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

We have a `Suppliers` class and a `Products` class. We wish to use Entity Framework Core to update our database when a supplier issues a new products catalog. Simplified classes:

```
public class Supplier
{
    public Guid SupplierId { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; } = new List<Product>();
}
public class Product
{
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemCost { get; set; }
    public Guid SupplierId { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

We wish to first delete items in the new catalog which are not in our old catalog. We try to find those items with this LINQ query

```
List<Product> discontinued = db.Products
.Where(e => !newCatalog
.Any(nc => (e.ItemCode == nc.ItemCode && e.SupplierId == nc.SupplierId))
.ToList();
```

We then delete using

```
db.Products.RemoveRange(discontinued);
```

However the query returns all products where `Products.SupplierId != newCatalog.SupplierId`. This deletes all products for other suppliers.

How do we formulate the LINQ query so that we only delete items that are discontinued in `newCatalog`?

Comment: I guess `newCatalog` is `List<Product>` for single `SupplierId` which you already have as parameter?

Comment: That is correct @Ivan Stoev

Comment: Then it should be something like `Where(e => e.SupplierId == supplierId && !newCatalog.Any(nc => nc.ItemCode == e.ItemCode))`

Comment: I mislead you in my earlier comment @Ivan Stoev. supplierId isn't passed as a parameter, every product in newCatalog has the same SupplierId, so we must extract supplierId from newCatalog in the query.

Comment: Well, then you can extract it from the `newCatalog` in advance, e.g. `var supplierId = newCatalog.Select(e => e.SupplierId).Distinct().Single();`

Comment: That did the trick thank you @Ivan Stoev

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Please propose as answer and I will mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct condition is

```
Where(e => e.SupplierId == supplierId && !newCatalog.Any(nc => nc.ItemCode == e.ItemCode))
```

which requires knowing the `SupplierId` of the passed products. It could be extracted in advance with something like this:

```
var supplierId = newCatalog.Select(e => e.SupplierId).Distinct().Single();
```

Here `Select` + `Distinct` + `Single` is simply to ensure all passed products have one and the same `SupplierId`. If you don't need such enforcement, you could simply take it from the first product:

```
var supplierId = newCatalog[0].SupplierId;
```

In both cases it's good to extract it and put it into variable outside of the query.

Another improvement could be to replace `newCatalog.Any(nc => nc.ItemCode == e.ItemCode)` condition which most likely is causing client evaluation with `Contains` based condition, hopefully converted to SQL `IN (...)` and evaluated on the server. To do that, again you could extract the new item codes into a new variable outside the query:

```
var newItemCodes = newCatalog.Select(nc => nc.ItemCode);
```

Then the final criteria inside the query would be:

```
Where(e => e.SupplierId == supplierId && !newItemCodes.Contains(e.ItemCode))
```